# Can I run npm package using yarn without installing that package?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Using `npm` you can use not locally installed package (missing in local `node_modules`) like this

`npx @angular/cli ng new`

which will install cli to the cache and use it (`node_modules` in project are intact)

can I do this with `yarn` ??

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using yarn v1.

In yarn v2+, you can use `yarn dlx`

```
yarn dlx @angular/cli ng new
```

See https://yarnpkg.com/cli/dlx for documentation